# Spring Test @Autowired Environment

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to write a test case in JUnit for a health check service method and as part of it, I would like to instantiate an Environment object from spring within the test.

Within the app I am able to

```
@Autowire
Environment env;
```

Which gives me an instantiated object, but not the case with Test class.

What complicates this scenario is that this is a "drop in" service/controller that is designed to be imported into other apps and not function on it's own and therefore lacks the typical classes required for a spring app.

```
public class HealthCheckServiceTest {


@Autowired
Environment environment;

private HealthCheckService healthCheckService;

@Before
public void loadGitPropertiesFile() throws Exception {
    healthCheckService = new HealthCheckService();
    healthCheckService.setEnvironment(environment);
}

@Test
public void testStatus() throws Exception {
    //Test to see if Health Check results are returned
}

}
```

Comment: You should provide spring configuration to test class within correct annotations. Please search in google something like `junit with spring` for more details.

Comment: In this case, you are probably missing something like...  `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"myConfig.xmll"})`

Comment: Hi Florian, I have RunWith but my problem with ContextConfiguration is that this is a health check service that lives inside of other services (get imported as a dependency and collected as part of the scan path), it is not a standalone app. Is it still normal to include a "myConfig.xml"?

Comment: This solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882038/how-to-mock-environment-interface