# How to mock Environment Interface

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I have to fetch path from the property file using Environment interface. In Junits I am not able to mock the Environment Interface. Below is my code. I want something random if I will call the method mentioned. How can I do it?

```
@Mock
    private Class object;
 @InjectMocks
    Class2 object2;

Mockito.when(object.getFilePath()).thenReturn("Random String");
```

Comment: Environment Interface is your own interface or a interface from a lib ?

Comment: It is framework interface... org.springframework.core.env.Environment; @davidxxx

Comment: You could use MockEnvironment from Spring

Comment: can you please tell me how to use  MockEnvironment from Spring??

Comment: I posted a simple example. If you have troubles, edit your question to give more details about your need.

Answer (score 8):

As said in my comment, you  don't need Mockito, you can use `MockEnvironment` class to mock `Environment` from Spring.
You can set values in this way :

```
    MockEnvironment environment = new MockEnvironment();
    environment.setProperty("yourKeyOne", "yourValue1");
    environment.setProperty("yourKeyTwo", "yourValue2");
```

And according to your need, you can use this environment variable.
For example, here is with an `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` instance :

```
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setEnvironment(environment);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mockito, you can do it as follows.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SampleMockitoTest {
    
    @Mock
    private Environment mockEnvironment;
    
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        //use mockEnvironment here
        when(environment.getProperty("yourKey")).thenReturn("yourValue");
    }
}
```